# Install MongoDB PHP driver (64bit linux)

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

I am unable to install php mongodb driver on 64-bit linuz based system.

I have followed [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) manual installation guide (because pecl installs older version of driver)

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make all
$ sudo make install
```

**make all** command gives

```
    /mongodb_master/php_mongo.c:89: error: ‘PHP_FE_END’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 1
```

I have followed [PHP_FE_FUNCTION : C error when trying to enable extension](https://serverfault.com/questions/317463/php-fe-function-c-error-when-trying-to-enable-extension) but no success.

Comment: What is your system exactly? Can't you use some kind of repository to install this?

Comment: This question on serverfault might be related:

http://serverfault.com/questions/317463/php-fe-function-c-error-when-trying-to-enable-extension

Comment: @ZeWaren I have already mentioned above link in my question.Server is `64 bit` with `PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21` installed

Answer (score 0):

&%$##$%& I thought this macro was defined in 5.3.0, apparently not Sorry!
However. You seem to be installing the current master, which will become 1.5.0.. I don't recommend doing that as that is still work-in-progress.

To workaround this for now, you can add in php_mongo.h (doesn't really matter where) the following line:

```
#define PHP_FE_END         { NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0 }
```

You should download the latest 1.4.x driver (currently 1.4.5).
If "pecl install mongo" does not fetch the 1.4.5 driver, then you should download the .tgz package from pecl instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem yesterday and i solved it by reinstalling my php.hope this may help you.